# UITableView does not repopulate with reloadData

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableView that successfully populates with a NSMutableArray. However, when I try to use a search function that I have implemented, the UITableView does not repopulate at all.

The NSMutableArray also contains the correct number of objects according to the search but when realoadData is called, the numberOfSections and numberOfRows methods are called, but the cellForRow method is not (even though the search returns 1 item). The delegate and datasource for the UITableView are correctly set up and connected using IB.

I am happy to paste some code, but I am unsure as to what relevant code would be helpful in discussion here.

Thanks

Comment: Answer: Just me being stupid and using a saved NSArray rather than the updated NSMutableArray to populate the table. 

Silly me...

Comment: @vonKoon... why not put in an answer and accept it. It will help you build your S/O points and can be helpful to other users.

Comment: It wouldn't let me do that for another 6 hours due to my S/O points being too low.

Comment: oh that's right... I forgot. It's been a while :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Just me being stupid and using a saved NSArray rather than the updated NSMutableArray to populate the table. Silly me...